# FLUTTER - Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly: "FileSystemException: Deletion failed, path = '...\.ios' )

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

Flutter IOS directory has been accidentally deleted

```
Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly: "FileSystemException: Deletion failed, path = 'C:\Users\USER\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_project\.ios' (OS Error: The directory is not empty. , errno = 145)".
```

The solution to this problem is below.

Answer (score 1):

THE SOLUTION IS:

RUN THE COMMAND BELOW IN YOUR FLUTTER PROJECT

```
1. flutter clean
2. flutter pub get
```

AND ERROR WILL BE GONE